# How to calculate the sum of time difference for every entry and exit per employee for each day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i'm using this dataframe , each employee have a unique ID and in column E/X , 6 represent the time he entered and 1 represent the time he left

```
Emp E/X             DateTime        Date     Time
107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
107 6 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52
107 6 2022-01-04  11:39:59 0 2022-01-04 11:39:59
107 1 2022-01-04  12:05:26 0 2022-01-04 12:05:26
107 6 2022-01-04  18:02:18 0 2022-01-04 18:02:18
107 6 2022-01-04  18:30:38 0 2022-01-04 18:30:38
107 1 2022-01-04  19:06:58 0 2022-01-04 19:06:58
107 1 2022-01-05  12:22:10 0 2022-01-05 12:22:10
107 6 2022-01-05  19:22:15 0 2022-01-05 19:22:15
122 1 2022-01-03  08:57:40 0 2022-01-03 08:57:40
122 6 2022-01-03  12:49:33 0 2022-01-03 12:49:33
122 1 2022-01-03  13:22:28 0 2022-01-03 13:22:28
122 6 2022-01-03  16:29:51 0 2022-01-03 16:29:51
122 1 2022-01-03  16:40:06 0 2022-01-03 16:40:06
```

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate how much the employee worked each day and change the E/X column so that each day has a successive in/out because it has errors sometimes there's multiple entries successively for exemple im gonna take the first two rows and change the second one into exit :

```
    Emp E/X           DateTime        Date     Time
    107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
    107 1 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52

    122 6 2022-01-03  08:57:40 0 2022-01-03 08:57:40
    122 1 2022-01-03  12:49:33 0 2022-01-03 12:49:33
    122 6 2022-01-03  13:22:28 0 2022-01-03 13:22:28
    122 1 2022-01-03  16:29:51 0 2022-01-03 16:29:51 this line is going to be deleted 
    122 1 2022-01-03  16:40:06 0 2022-01-03 16:40:06
```

**desired result :**

```
    Emp E/X             DateTime        Date     Time
    107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
    107 1 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52
    107 6 2022-01-04  11:39:59 0 2022-01-04 11:39:59
    107 1 2022-01-04  12:05:26 0 2022-01-04 12:05:26
    107 6 2022-01-04  18:02:18 0 2022-01-04 18:02:18
    107 1 2022-01-04  19:06:58 0 2022-01-04 19:06:58
    107 6 2022-01-05  12:22:10 0 2022-01-05 12:22:10
    107 1 2022-01-05  19:22:15 0 2022-01-05 19:22:15
    122 6 2022-01-03  08:57:40 0 2022-01-03 08:57:40
    122 1 2022-01-03  12:49:33 0 2022-01-03 12:49:33
    122 6 2022-01-03  13:22:28 0 2022-01-03 13:22:28

    122 1 2022-01-03  16:40:06 0 2022-01-03 16:40:06
```

and once the E/X is fixed i want to calculate the sum of every difference between 6 and 1 per employee for each day

**Desired Result:**

```
    EMP           Date  WorkHours    
4   107     2022-01-03  2
5   107     2022-01-04  8
6   122     2022-01-03  4
```

Comment: Why employee 117 disappears?

Comment: I took just the first 2 rows to show the processing because it has to be like that entry and then exit

Comment: the logic around cleaning up entry and exit seems really unclear and unintuitive. The data shows Employee 117 enters then 107 enters but for some reason you can't have two consecutive entries so 107 must have been mistakenly recorded as an exit? How do you know that 117 wasn't mistakenly recorded as an entry? Or that data isn't missing?

Comment: its a mistake there's no employee 117 its edited now

Comment: Please check your first desired result. I feel something goes wrong.

Comment: There's multiple ways you could convert a non-alternating sequence to one that is alternating. In your example you change values, or drop a row. You need to explicitly state the approach you are taking.

Comment: the number of entry/exit for employee have to be pair that's why i droped a row so i can make the time difference , and also starts with 6 and ends with 1

Comment: What I'm getting at is your sequence gets out of order at 18:30:38.  Do you drop this one?  Do you drop 18:02:18?  Maybe there was an exit between these times that didn't get recorded? Do you keep both and change 18:30:38 to an entry and 19:06:58 to an exit?  Would your answer depend on whether 12:22:10 was an entry or exit?

Comment: i have to drop the 18:30:38 because the number of rows has to be pair and leave the last one and change it to exit so i can do the process the whole process is going to be like this :  6 then 1  until the end of the day 6-1-6-1- but i cant have this 6-1-6-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to use my own test data and assume it is already clean, i.e. alternating start/end datetimes

**setup**

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "employee":[107]*6,
                "E/X":[6,1,6,1,6,1],
                "datetime":pd.Timestamp("2022") + pd.Series([0,4,14,26,40,50]).apply(pd.Timedelta, unit="hours")
            }
        ),
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "employee":[122]*8,
                "E/X":[6,1,6,1,6,1,6,1],
                "datetime":pd.Timestamp("2022") + pd.Series([3,20,30,35,45,55,56,60]).apply(pd.Timedelta, unit="hours")
            }
        ),
    ]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df` looks like this

```
    employee  E/X            datetime
0        107    6 2022-01-01 00:00:00
1        107    1 2022-01-01 04:00:00
2        107    6 2022-01-01 14:00:00
3        107    1 2022-01-02 02:00:00
4        107    6 2022-01-02 16:00:00
5        107    1 2022-01-03 02:00:00
6        122    6 2022-01-01 03:00:00
7        122    1 2022-01-01 20:00:00
8        122    6 2022-01-02 06:00:00
9        122    1 2022-01-02 11:00:00
10       122    6 2022-01-02 21:00:00
11       122    1 2022-01-03 07:00:00
12       122    6 2022-01-03 08:00:00
13       122    1 2022-01-03 12:00:00
```

**solution**

This will use a package called [piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io) (pandas interval set operations).  In particular it will follow the last example of [piso.coverage](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.coverage.html#piso.coverage)

```
# create day range required and convert to interval index
days = pd.date_range("2022", freq="D", periods=4)
day_intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(days)

# creates an interval index from start and end times for an employee
# then calculates the sum of each interval for each bin in day_intervals
def calc_employee(d):
    ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(d.loc[d["E/X"] == 6, "datetime"], d.loc[d["E/X"] == 1, "datetime"])
    return piso.coverage(ii, domain=day_intervals, bins=True, how="sum")

# apply the function for each employee
hours_worked = df.groupby("employee").apply(calc_employee)

# columns will be day_intervals, let's change it to the start of each day
hours_worked.columns = hours_worked.columns.left

# melt it into tidy data format
hours_worked = hours_worked.melt(var_name="date", value_name="timedelta", ignore_index=False).reset_index()

# calculate hours from timedelta value (optional)
hours_worked["hours"] = hours_worked["timedelta"]/pd.Timedelta("1hr")
```

`hours_worked` looks like this:

```
   employee       date       timedelta  hours
0       107 2022-01-01 0 days 14:00:00   14.0
1       122 2022-01-01 0 days 17:00:00   17.0
2       107 2022-01-02 0 days 10:00:00   10.0
3       122 2022-01-02 0 days 08:00:00    8.0
4       107 2022-01-03 0 days 02:00:00    2.0
5       122 2022-01-03 0 days 11:00:00   11.0
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: i tried this but i got an error : `ValueError: left and right must have the same length`

Comment: There was a typo in the calc employee function which I've now fixed

Comment: does it work on any other dataframe ? because i tried with another one and still getting that error

Comment: It needs to have the same format, and it needs to have the same number of 6 as 1 in the E/X column, for each employee

Comment: if you're missing an exit at the end of the data, just insert one with a future value

Comment: yeah I got it, thanks a lot for the help, but I'm still trying to figure out how to clean the E/X column  and reorganize it

Comment: You can always use Series.diff on the E/X column and drop zeroes.  This will always pick the first in a sequence of same E/X values.  Is this the right thing to do?  That depends completely on your problem, what you're doing with the results, and how errors in the data are generated.